# What is the correct or most optimal way to drawing dynamic geometry

Tags: c++, opengl

what is the best way to handle vertex data objects that are constantly changing (eg: animated 3D models).For static geometry, the best way (i believe) is store vertex data in a single VBO (vertextBuffer Object) and then bind this into a VAO (Vertex Array Object).But I have not idea how to handle the dynamic geomtry. It uses a VBO for each model? and then linked to a single VAO?

Answer (score 2):

Transformation matrices.

You should know about the MVP (Model View and Projection) matrices, right? well consider "sub-model" ones, the view matrix positions me in a scene, the model matrix rotates me, any offsets that make sense (move my local origin to my torso rather than my left foot maybe....) so forth.

Now consider my upper-arm, it is rotated/positioned relative to my torso, which is positioned by the MV (model view) matrix, so using U for upper arm, and v for a vertex, PVMUv is for the vertices of my upper arm, we first move them by U, then by M, then by V then project the result (V would be a column vector, I prefer the mathematicians way)

Now consider L, my lower arm, relative to my upper arm. and redefine v as a vertex of my lower arm.

PVMULv first translates a vertex by L, which could be a rotation (about the local origin, or elbow), which is then transformed by U which can be though of as the shoulder, then by PVM as usual. Now if you change U, the lower arm moves with it, and if you change L only the lower arm vertices are affected.

This is the basics of skeletal animation. It means you need only store one set of geometry and just push matrices back and forth as you would anyway. If you are playing animations in the model file you'd store UL for lower-arm vertices, that way you wouldn't have to calculate it at runtime, this makes sense provided the animator handles limbs at compile (or 'design' time)

Comment: Most character models are rigged to a skeleton in such a way that each vertex's position depends on some blending of the transformations of multiple nearby bones instead of just copying a single bone's transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was a great help! I thank you for so much effort into the answer. On the other hand my question was focused on the following:

For each 3D model must create a separate Vbo? And then add it to a single vao?

I am very grateful

Comment: @user2303826 you should accept it, click the tick, if it answered your question.